# Calling super method from within super class

Tags: java

As a brain-twister example a professor of mine gave us following exercise, to learn about inheritance. We had to figure out the output.

```
//java
public class A {
    public void f() {
        System.out.println("A -> f()");
        x = x + 4;
        if (x < 15) this.f(); //the f-call
    }
    public int x = 5;
}

public class B extends A {
    @Override
    public void f() {
        System.out.println("B -> f()");
        x = x + 3;
        super.f();
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void
    main(String[] args) {
        A a = new B();

        System.out.println("a.f()");
        a.f();
        System.out.println(a.x);
    }
}
```

The output is, as I expected,

- a.f()
- B -> f()
- A -> f()
- B -> f()
- A -> f()
- 19

However, I was now wondering. Is there a way to make *the f-call* in A call the f method in A, even when I use it from an B-object, similar to the way I call the f from A in B using super.f(). So the output would become (I think):

- a.f()
- B -> f()
- A -> f()
- A -> f()
- 16

Is this possible? And if so, how?

Note: I'm not sure what the practical application of this would be, I'm just trying to learn something new :P

Comment: So essentially, you want a method to call itself? I don't think you can do that

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want it to do.

Comment: @CharlesWhitfield Of course a method can call itself. It's called a recursive method. OP's question is whether it's possible to specify the parent version of a method from within the parent class.

Comment: @shmosel - Ah Sorry! Now, I see.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is "no" you cannot do this.

The longer answer is that allowing this would break all kinds of guarantees about inheritance.  Your B class has essentially said "I now provide the canonical method for `public void f()`".  Because `B` is providing said method it is allowed to call back in to the parent to use that (and something that's a very useful thing to do).

If `A` was allowed to do the same it would essentially be bypassing the behaviour that `B` wants to override.

There are a variety of patterns available that give you *similar* behaviour, e.g. [the Template Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern)

Answer (score 2):

Because polymorphism will apply to all methods of a superclass object, the `f` that is called will be that of the object's runtime type always -- in this case, `B`, so `B`'s `f` method will always be called.  That cannot be changed in Java.

You may be able to work around this by doing the work of `A`'s `f` method in a `private` method, say, `foo`, so that when `f` is called, `foo` is called repeatedly.  In `A`:

```
public void f()
{
   foo();
}

private void foo() {
    System.out.println("A -> f()");  // Lie.
    x = x + 4;
    if (x < 15) this.foo(); //the "f"-call
}
```